# Accessing subclass methods within a vector of of superclass objects

Tags: java, object, inheritance, vector, abstract-class

I am using a vector to store objects of an abstract superclass. I need to access a method(s) within the derived subclasses of each object in the vector. I will be using `instanceof` in order to differentiate which subclass each object is a part of.

I do not have permission to write to the abstract class.

Currently the compile error I am getting is:

> `Error: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   method <mySubclassMethod>()
>     location: class <MyAbstractClass>`

What is the most effective way of going about accessing the subclass methods of each object within my vector?

Comment: might be easy to give the best solution if you can post your code you tried.

Comment: There is a fundamental flaw with the way you are trying to call methods on objects in a collection by adding an instanceOf check and calling different methods only present in each of the subclass. In my opinion, you can post another question that asks for a good design to solve your problem and scrap this quesiton completely because even if you do manage to get an answer to this quesiton, its not a good way to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the object to the subclass inside of an `instanceof` guard.

```
if (obj instanceof MySubclass)
    ((MySubclass)obj).mySubclassMethod();
```

More broadly, if the method should be available in all of your subclasses, you should add it to the abstract superclass. Then, when you call the method on the 'uncasted' abstract superclass object, it will use the implementation from the proper subclass.

```
public abstract class MySuperclass {
    public abstract void mySubclassMethod();
    ...
}

public class MySubclass extends MySuperclass {
    @Override
    public void mySublcassMethod() { ... }
    ...
}
...

MySuperclass obj = [actually a Subclass];
obj.mySubclassMethod(); // uses the implementation from MySubclass
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is to create the method as abstract in your superclass.  Then, what you will do is override this method in each of your subclasses.  This will allow you to access that method for all the different objects in that vector of yours.

I'm assuming this method will vary depending on your subclass, otherwise, why wouldn't you just write that method in the superclass in the first place.